# Running sort function in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am running the following code below across multiple tabs, both `criteria1` and `criteria2` work fine but when I add `crietria3` I get the error

> "Named Argument not found"

Basically, The first part of the code (before the `criteria1` code) is just a simple division of figures from the first cell and that gets converted into percentages.

- `criteria1` Sorts one column and extracts cells with the specific figures listed below.
- `Criteria2` Hides unnecessary columns that I don't need.
- `Criteria3` then proceeds to Filter the `AD` column by largest to smallest and that is where the code breaks with the *"Named Argument not found"* error.

Can you please help?

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Range("AD1").Value = "In %"
        ws.Range("AD1").Font.Bold = True
        With ws.Range("AD2:AD91")
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/R2C28"
            .Style = "Percent"
            .NumberFormat = "0.0%"
            .Font.Bold = True
            ws.Range("A1:AD91").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("11", "21", "22""23", "31-33", "42", "44-45", "48-49", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "61", "62", "71", "72", "81"), Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=ws.Range("A:A,I1,F:F,C:E,I:AA").EntireColumn.Hidden = True, Criteria3:=ws.Range("AD1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= xlSortNormal
        End With
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably not related to the problem, but shouldn't `"22""23"` be `"22","23"`

Comment: Yes, it should be, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are actually trying to do (you didn't explain) but according to [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-autofilter-method-excel) a `Criteria3` parameter does not exist. So your syntax is not valid. There is only `Criteria1` and `Criteria2`.

Comment: So, how would I add a third criteria? To sort in descending order?

Comment: I recommend to use the Macro Recorder. Then do the filtering manually (while recording it) and look how the generated macro does it. Then try to apply this technique to your code. This is an easy way to find out how things work in VBA.

Comment: Okay, thank you. That makes sense.

Comment: Does `Criteria2` work? `Criteria2:=ws.Range("A:A,I1,F:F,C:E,I:AA").EntireColumn.Hidden = True`.  I don't get how the `.EntireColumn.Hidden = True` bit works.

Comment: Yes, it does, that basically hides a bunch of columns mentioned in the range. The Crtieria 3 is where the code breaks with the error - "Named Argument not found." Criteria 3 is for sorting AD1 column by highest to lowest values.

Comment: @DK7 Well, but criteria 2 doesn't make sense at all to me. If you want to hide columns then you don't do that in a criteria. Do that *before* you filter.

Comment: And then put criteria 2 as the sort function?

Comment: Since you never explained anything in the question above yet, we can only guess what you are actually trying. But give it a try (it's all about try and error), and if that dosen't work record a macro and see what you get. If this all still doesn't work, update your original question with what you have tried and explain what went wrong or where you got errors.

Comment: @DK7: Autofilter can only have 2 criteria... have a look at [Mr Excel: AutoFilter Code not working](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/595371-autofilter-code-not-working.html)

Comment: I have edited the original question to better articulate what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

I separated your first criteria into an array for better readability when filtering for these values.

This should loop through sheets, hide columns (I removed this `I1`, typo?), filter by your `Arr1`, and then sort values in column AD in descending order.

You also end your sub by turning off screen updating. I'm not sure if that was intentional or not. Updated here to turn off `ScreenUpdating` before loop starts, and re-enabled at end of sub.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro2()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Arr1

Arr1 = Array("11", "21", "22", "23", "31-33", "42", "44-45", "48-49", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "61", "62", "71", "72", "81")

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Range("A:A,C:F,I:AA").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ws.Range("AD1").Value = "In %"
        ws.Range("AD1").Font.Bold = True
            With ws.Range("AD2:AD91")
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/R2C28"
                .Style = "Percent"
                .NumberFormat = "0.0%"
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With
        ws.Range("A1:AD91").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Arr1
        ws.Range("A1:AD91").Sort Range("AD2"), xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    Next ws
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```